# Is it possible to preload image outside of the React component the image will render in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, preload

I built a system where I have a loading page. In this loading page I can call this function:

```
export const preloadImage = ( name, width, height ) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = `MY DYNAMIC IMAGE URL (private)`;
    img.onload = () => {
      store.dispatch(addSavedimage([name, img.src])); //addSavedImage is a redux action
      resolve();
    };
  });
};
```

So what this function does is load my image in a `new Image()`. Then it waits until the image is loaded. Normally if I do this inside the component where the image resides the image tag src becomes the preloaded image src when it loads, but because this is not the case here I give the preloaded image src to Redux. When I want to use this preloaded image I simply retrieve it from the Redux store but then it just downloads the image again.

So my question is, how do I preload my image outside my image component?

Comment: It's most likely your browser not caching the image. Have you got `disable cache` ticked while having developer tools open?

Comment: @AvinKavish No I made sure that this was unchecked.

Comment: hmmm....most probably since the image element gets garbage collected when this promise is resolved, the cached image gets evicted as well. Try pushing the image element to the store and setting the src from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to be happening is that the cached image is evicted as the image element goes out of scope (and gets garbage collected) when the promise is resolved. You can keep the image in scope by dispatching it to the store. After you navigate to the next component you can set the image `src` directly from it.

```js
export const preloadImage = ( name, width, height ) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = `MY DYNAMIC IMAGE URL (private)`;
    img.onload = () => {
      store.dispatch(addSavedimage([name, img])); // <-- dispatch img element itself
      resolve();
    };
  });
};
```

Note: With this method, two image elements will exist for each source image. In order to save memory, consider clearing the image store once all `src`s have been added to the DOM.